# Why dispatch in my react app is not working?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using redux for the first time. I'm not much familiar with it.I want to call createTicket function when submit button clicked and for the instance I need to do console log.
**ticketAction.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import TicketService from './../AddTicketService';
import * as ActionTypes from './../actionTypes/tickets.ActionTypes';

export const createTicket = (formData) => {
  console.log("1");
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.CREATE_TICKET_IN_PROGRESS
    });

    console.log(formData);
    const formattedFormData = {
      ...formData,
    };

    TicketService.create(
      formattedFormData
    )
      .then(() => dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.CREATE_TICKET_COMPLETED }))
      .catch((error) =>
        dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.CREATE_TICKET_FAILED,
          payload: error.response.data
        })
      );
  };
};
```

It logs `1` in the console.But rest inside the return is not working.

Below is the reducer file
ticketsReducer.js

```
import * as ActionTypes from './../actionTypes/tickets.ActionTypes';
// import _ from 'loadash';

const initialState = {
  createTicketStatus: {
    inProgress: false,
    error: null
  }
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.CREATE_TICKET_IN_PROGRESS:
        console.log('CREATE_TICKET_IN_PROGRESS');
      return {
        ...state,
        createTicketStatus: {
          inProgress: true,
          error: null
        }
      };
    case ActionTypes.CREATE_TICKET_COMPLETED:
      return {
        ...state,
        createTicketStatus: {
          inProgress: false,
          error: null
        }
      };
    case ActionTypes.CREATE_TICKET_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        createTicketStatus: {
          inProgress: false,
          error: action.payload
        }
      };

      default: // need this for default case
      return state 
   
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error !
Instead if importing and calling this function createTicket, we have to call it using props.
`this.props.createTicket(data);`
If you need more clarifications do let me know!